# Rsync from remote server to local computer with no public IP

Tags: linux, rsync, ip, ssh-tunneling

I want to rsync a folder from a server in public network to a system in my local network.

```
(lets assume the local system is X)
```

The local system does have Internet connection but does not have a public IP assigned to it so that I may directly transfer files into it.

I want the public server to send me files and not my local system to get files from the server.

I have this local system in network with a machine which has a public assigned to it.

```
(lets call it Y)
```

I can transfer the folder/files from a public server to my machine having a public ip (from public server to Y) and then from that public ip machine to my local machine(Y to X) but it is a time taking process

Can I someone use ssh tunnel to directly get stuffs from the public server to my target local machine ?

```
ie from Server to X directly ?
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, there should be many solution for this ;)

- You could automate the intermediate copy with a script
- A tunnel can be created which connects a port on X to a port on the public machine. So you could probably run rsync on X. I played with tunnels a couple of years back, but found them somewhat unreliable if started manually. However, [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) automates the connection, and maintains tunnel alive.

Still, if X has internet access, it will be using a public IP at some point. I wonder why you are not able to use rsync directly? NAT at the router should translate a port at the public IP to an internal IP without any problem? Or am I confused?