# How to update a local mirror from a public server?

Tags: rsync, wget, slackware, software-updates, lftp

I already have a mirror of the entire **slackware64-current/** directory tree using

> wget -r -np -R "index.html*" https://mirror.slackbuilds.org/slackware/slackware64-current/

and that's fine. But it's getting a bit old, and I'd like to update just the changed files. **rsync** would work great, but I don't have an ssh  **username@...** for that **mirror.slackbuilds.org/** site. Is there any way to **rsync** publicly-accessible files from a remote server without a **username@**?

Alternatively, I've browsed the manpages for **lftp** and **wget**, but am not seeing exactly how to construct the appropriate commands. It seems like **lftp** would do the trick if I could figure out exactly how, but the manpage isn't entirely clear (to me).

So what, and exactly how, is the best way to sync up a local directory tree from a publicly accessible remote server (without any ssh username or other privileges)? It looks like [Rsync from remote server to local computer with no public IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369175/) is asking basically the same question, but not getting a suitable answer (at least not for my purposes). And, by the way, it would be great to also have an **rsync  -n** type of option, so that I could see what needed updating before actually updating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `-N` flag to wget:

> Wget will ask the server for the last-modified date. If the local file has the same timestamp as the server, or a newer one, the remote file will not be re-fetched. However, if the remote file is more recent, Wget will proceed to fetch it.

[more info](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping)